# Is "prominence" a verb?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

The word "prominence" seems like it is being used as a verb in the definition below – am I wrong?

> *work done by several associates with each doing a part but all subordinating personal prominence to the efficiency of the whole*

This sentence comes from the definition of the word *teamwork* by [Merriam-Webster's online dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/teamwork).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There, the subject of *subordinating* is *all*, and the object is *personal prominence*.  So it is still a noun.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I misunderstood "subordinating" as an adjective.